# Jsoup : how to get elements with an attribute equals to another element attribute

Tags: jsoup

To be more precise, I need to extract all the image-maps of a page.

A well-formed image-map is defined as follows :

```
<img src="image.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="My Image" usemap="#mymap">

<map name="mymap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="page1.htm" alt="Area1">
    <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="page2.htm" alt="Area2">
    <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="page3.htm" alt="Area3">
</map>
```

The required "name" attribute of the `<map>` element is associated with the `<img>`'s "usemap" attribute and creates a relationship between the image and the map.

How can I keep the well-formed `<map>` and thus skip all the ones whose "name" attribute doesn't correspond to any 's "usemap" attribute of any `<img>`?

Is it possible to avoid to select all the `<img>` elements with a "usemap" attribute and all the `<map>` elements with a "name" attribute and compare them one by one?

In this case, xpath enables to do something like

```
 //map[concat('#', @name) = //img/@usemap]"
```

Is there any equivalent?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Koj

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
    Elements mapElements = doc.select("map");
    for (Iterator<Element> map = mapElements.iterator(); map.hasNext();)
    {
        Element element = map.next();
        Elements imageElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("usemap", "#" + element.attr("name"));
        if(imageElements.size() == 0){
                // No <img> corresponds to this <map>, do whatever you like
        }
    }
```